# Is it possible to receive a gift on Steam and put it in your inventory if you already own it?

Tags: steam

I own Portal.

As part of the sale that's going on, there is a lot of trading going on. I am trying to get a few things together to make a trade with another person.

A person sent me Portal via email. When I click on the link, where it would normally prompt me for what to do with the gift (library or inventory) I just go to my inventory page but nothing has changed.

The email it was sent to is the same as the address on the steam account.

Is this possible? I see nothing about it on the Steam forums. Anyone ever do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This didn't use to be possible, but it has been fixed now. The old gifting system has been integrated with the inventory.

When you click the "Accept Gift" button in the "pending gifts" section of your inventory, you'll get the option of storing it in your Steam Inventory.

[image: Add to my Steam Gift Inventory]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I'm waiting to hear from Valve if this is indeed the case.

Comment: "Directly through Steam" doesn't work either if the recipient owns the game -- they're greyed out in the list and it says they already own it.  A trade seems to be the only option.